# is there any way to execute binaries without importing anything from .py scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, python, c, gcc, binary

First of all i created binaries of python scripts using following commands in ubuntu-16.04:

`cython3 --embed -o hello.c hello.py`

`gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o hello hello.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl`

But there are some issues which i need to discuss:

1- If i delete python scripts than binaries gives import error(which are importing from .py files).

2- And if i do not delete .py files than all the binaries working perfectly(which is totally makes nonsense of the creation of binaries)

Now i know the issue is running files are binaries and the import some constants and functions in binaries are from .py scripts.

my project code flow is:

```
**Main folder**
  **Scripts1 Folder**
        Script1.py
        Script2.py
        Script3.py & many other .py scripts...
        **Scrip1.1 Folder**
               Script1_1.py
               Script1_2.py & many .py scripts
  **Script2 Folder**
        Script1.py
        Script2.py & many other .py scripts
```

Is there any way to execute binaries which have all import constants/functions in it at the time of creation?

and is there any way to gernerate binares from .c code of .py using gcc which will be executeable without have any .py scripts in it?

And also there will be no issue of importing from .py scripts.

**Example:**

from script1 import function1

from script1_2 import constants

Actually the issue is this import is from python script in binary file and i want this import in binary from another binary file. when i delete the .py scripts from the folder the error is "Import error: cannot import function1 from script1. There is no such a file script1.py"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want something like a standalone statically linked binary but from python code? And why? This will lose one of the great advantages of scripting languages - that is to allow to quickly read and adapt what happens without spending a year to hunt down the source code (as recently happened to me with a Linux-based VoIP phone)

Comment: @BernhardM. Yes i want binaries but not linked with python code. This is the actual issue i want just stand alone binaries which will be executable without any help of any python scripts? 
Do you have any solution for this according to my project structure?

Comment: Have you tried what is explained at this page - https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html  ? First compile python to c, and then club everything together ?

Comment: @amisax thanks for your response but yes i tried it and compiler my python scripts into .so file but when i execute .so file it gives an error “Segmentation fault (core dumped)”